# How to draw with Pine-script on Tradingview charts only for a single specific asset?

Tags: pine-script

I have found many examples of drawing with Pinescript on Tradingview charts.
Unfortunately, they all leave the drawings in place when the user selects a different asset.

My questions are simple:

1. Is it possible to have different drawings for each specific asset on a single specific layout?
2. What settings must be used to make that happen?

I would greatly appreciate an short example.

TIA.

Comment: You could add an [input.symbol()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_input.symbol) to your script and only plot/draw if the current symbol is the same as the selected asset from your indicator properties. Then just add your indicator multiple times to the same layout and set different properties for different assets.